# Route-Map vs ACL for Cisco NAT

Tags: networking, cisco, nat, ios

Is there pros and cons of using route-maps vs access-lists for network address translation on a cisco router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick bit of Googling found [this article](http://ccnprecertification.com/2005/04/01/nat-using-a-route-map/) - looks like the route-map implementation provides per-flow NAT entries, rather than per-destination. In cases where you have lots of NATted traffic between the same two end points, this might be helpful in troubleshooting what is going wrong with a particular flow.

Route-maps also allow you to perform [policy-based routing with NAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t4/feature/guide/ftnatrt.html) using the 'set ip next-hop' command within the route-map.

I've never looked into the route-map implementation, but one thing I would be interested in finding out is the relative throughput of the two implementations - I'd particularly expect that use of 'set ip next-hop' would have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, route-maps can match against extended access lists, whereas "ip nat inside source list" supports standard access lists only.